# Need help on regex to exclude strings that are not phone numbers

Tags: regex

I've got phone number data streaming as strings and sometimes I get junk like `ZF420` or `44CE8402`, which need to be excluded. The phone numbers are expressed as such -- `447711223344` etc. So, the regex I have developed thus far is:

```
[^0-9][^ ]\d{3}+[(\D)+(^ )]
```

However, the above works to match the likes of `ZF420`, `CC110`, etc. but not `44CE8402`. How should the regex be written to also match the latter (so I can throw them out)?

Comment: Do you mean to exclude any number that includes non-numbers? You didn't express your question clearly. BTW, why do you need regex for that anyway. There are a lot simpler and presumably more efficient ways for this.

Comment: Consider building a regexp to match *valid* phone numbers, instead of one to match *invalid* phone numbers. Usually doing it that way is easier. Especially since it sounds like valid phone number is `^\d{12}$`

Comment: Apologies, yes, i meant to exclude any non-numbers.

Comment: Well, which would be better in terms of performance if 5 million phone numbers come through during run-time and potentially only up to 4 could be non-valids? To match to exclude non-valids OR to match to include valid numbers only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
^(\d{12})$
```

It just matches a string of length 12 which are all digits.

But if this is the case and it's just literally a string with only digits you want you would be better off checking to see if you could parse into a numeric data type successfully or not.

Comment: +1, but I disagree with your last paragraph: I think a regex is *exactly* the best way to do this. Something like `0x12` might parse as an integer, but it doesn't consist of twelve decimal digits.

Comment: @Ruakh I hadn't considered that! Good spot, I just perceived checking if a value is numeric to be overkill for regex when its usually used for more complex matching.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this one too:

```
[0-9]{12}
```

Comment: Thanks! This one and the ones above works.
However, at this point the question has now turned to asking which would be better to do -- match exclude non-valid or match for valid numbers only -- if less than 0.0000001% of the phone numbers that comes in are non-valid numbers?